# How to disable crash report popup from crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I want to disable this crash popup emitted from the crashlytics framework, but still send the crash.

[image: crashlytics' popup before sending a crash]

I've seen in the [doc](https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Crashlytics/Classes/Crashlytics.html#overview) that you can filter the dispatch using "CrashlyticsDelegate" but I can't figure out how to shut down this. (also the doc last update is *Last updated: 2017-01-20*, am I missing something here o.O)

Also using `strings` I see some methods such as:

- `alertWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitle:`
- `setupAndDisplayAlertWithTitle:message:cancel:send:alwaysSend:report:`

So the questions:

- Is it at least **possible to disable it**?
- If it is, **how**?

*I wonder if it comes from an older version of crashlytics, explaining maybe why I'm not able to find it in the doc~*

---

### EDIT: I tested the delegate's methods provided to intercept the crash before sending it

---

Using `- (void)crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:(CLSReport *)report;` the doc says (in the header since the internet doc isn't up to date):

- it is not called synchronously during initialization
- it does not give you the ability to prevent the report from being submitted
- the report object itself is immutable

**So this one doesn't provide any way of removing the popup.**

---

Using `- (void)crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:(CLSReport *)report completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL submit))completionHandler;` the doc says (in header again):

- Invoking completionHandler with **NO** will cause the detected report to be deleted and not submitted to Crashlytics. This is useful for implementing permission prompts, or other more-complex forms of logic around submitting crashes.

**Can't disable the popup here either.**

Moreover I don't see what is the point of having a "permission prompt" like they say if you can't remove theirs :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the privacy dialog pop-up in the app settings page

https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#use-the-privacy-dialog

Here is a screenshot of where it hides:

[image]

Comment: I so desperatly looked for something like `disablePopup` that I passed through the automatic behaviour that disable this thing. I'll test it as soon as I can and will mark it answered just after, thanks :)

Comment: I used the 2 different methods proposed on the delegate part but my only choice is to choose whether I want to send the report or not. It does not remove the popup. :( I will edit the question accordingly

Comment: Is the privacy dialog enabled for your app?

https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#use-the-privacy-dialog

Comment: If so, you can disable the privacy prompt

Comment: Finally! \o/ Yeap the option was there, Never found it, though I looked in the web settings too. Thank you. Consider answering the question so I can close it :)